# Multiple animations on imageView inside scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView inside which I have an ImageView. What I am trying to achieve is:
- zoom-in image to fit full height of the screen when user taps and zoom-out when user taps again,
- start automatically first animation which is scrolling to the right side of the image,
- after that, start second animation which is scrolling to the middle of the image,
- at last start again the animation scrolling to the right side of the image.
I would like to achieve the impression of image floating on the screen. User cannot scroll the image by himself.

I have already done the part with zooming, but the problem I have is with animations. I have tried something like this, where offset, middleOffset and endOffset are CGPoints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        setupGestureRecognizer()
    }

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }

fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(size: CGSize) {
        let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
        let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

        let maxHeightScale = view.frame.height / imageView.bounds.height
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = maxHeightScale

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
    }

fileprivate func updateConstraintsForSize(size: CGSize) {
        let yOffset = max(0, (size.height - imageView.frame.height) / 2)
        imageViewTopConstraint.constant = yOffset
        imageViewBottomConstraint.constant = yOffset

        let xOffset = max(0, (size.width - imageView.frame.width) / 2)
        imageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xOffset
        imageViewTrailingConstraint.constant = xOffset

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        updateMinZoomScaleForSize(size: view.bounds.size)
    }

    func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSingleTap(recognizer:)))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    }

    func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (scrollView.zoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.maximumZoomScale, animated: true)
        }
    }

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.3, options: [], animations: { 
            scrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.3, options: [], animations: {
                scrollView.setContentOffset(middleOffset, animated: false)
            }, completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.3, options: [], animations: {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(endOffset, animated: false)
                }, completion: nil)
            })
        })
    }

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updateConstraintsForSize(size: view.bounds.size)
}
```

Howewer it does not work. First animation loads after image is zoomed in, but then it stops (it does not crash). It seems like animation is not finished because I cannot zoom-out image when tapping again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that animation blocks cannot be inside of `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. I put them inside `handleSingleTap` function and then it works as it should.